# Time Format not working in Visual Studio versions after 2005

Tags: asp.net, gridview

While Binding DateTime I was using DateTime Format in Gridview.

```
Eval("slotdate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}").
```

Perfectly working in VS 2005 but in later version its throwing runtime error.

> Format not supported

Actually i have lot of pages in this project. Is there any solution so that i don't need to change in each page?

Comment: `What runtime error` you are getting?

Comment: did you change the framework version from 2.0?

Comment: now i converted to 3.5